# The next number in the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a form of an aptitude test. I just wanted to know what comes next in this series?

```
7 x 11 = 77; 63 x 101 = 6363; 234 x 1001 = 234234; 4189 x 10001 = 41894189
```

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be so many things. For example,

$$ 41678*10001 = 4167841678$$.